# task manager doesn't show graphs in performance

Tags: task-manager

when I go to performance and click cpu for example  , it doesn't show me graphs like the useage of each core , also doesn't show me the information like RAM speed etc.

basically when I click CPU , GPU , RAM etc nothing happened like on the picture

[image: taskmanager]

Comment: Please show us a screenshot of what you do see.

Comment: yes i put it in the question under the question

Answer (score 2):

The left and right area of Task Manager is separated with a movable separator. In your case, this separator is moved all the way to the right. If you move your mouse close to the right edge of the window until the ↔ arrow shows, you can drag it back to the left and get your graphs back.

Comment: dude i feel kinda stupid right now , that right fixed my problem

Comment: That's okay. happens to all of us. Feel free to mark the V if this answered your question so others know you no longer need help. :)